# What was "LCD CGA" graphics mode?

Tags: graphics-card, total-eclipse

In the old DOS game Total Eclipse, you can select from various graphics modes at the beginning.  One of them was CGA:

[image: CGA logo]

... but one of them was so-called "LCD CGA":

[image: LCD CGA logo]

Was this just their way of saying "CGA with a wacky palette", or was there some particular graphics hardware/monitor that this graphics mode was designed for?

Comment: Looks like a white on black mode.  CGA stands for [Color graphics Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_Graphics_Adapter). LCD means liquid crystal display.

Comment: I had a computer that displayed graphics like the bottom image, with lots of cyan and magenta. I always wondered why the Decathlon game had a color-check screen that showed a block labeled "green" that always showed cyan. I didn't realize there were two kinds of CGA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually very simple: back in the era of early DOS laptops (late eighties to early ninties) there were various implementations of CGA laptop screens, including small CRT monitors, plasma monitors and early LCDs. Some of these LCDs were fairly crude monochrome monitors and would display inversed colors.

Examples include, but are not limited to: SONY SMC-210DL6 (1986), Zenith SupersPort 286 (1988) or Tidalwave Pocket PC (1992) and its clones (Highscreen Handy Organizer etc.) with nonreflective mono supertwist display based on monochrome CGA with 640x200 resolution.

LCD CGA mode in Total Eclipse would be aimed at such machines, compensating their hardware colour inversion by inverting colours in the game so that the resulting image would be similar to other versions of the game.

Comment: If they were monochrome monitors, how did they display CGA?

Comment: Like this: http://www.imgrum.org/media/1149640832797949807_1831893374

Comment: That link isn't working.